# check if MySQL table is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if my table is empty I've tried this "which I think that is the solution"

```
$test_empty="SELECT *FROM objectif where 1 ";
if(empty($test_empty))
{
     echo "I m here";
}
```

But it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think `empty()` is going to work like that, see the [spec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).  You'll need to [open a connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to your database, run the query capturing the result and close the connection. You'll probably want to return the count which you can check == 0.  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM objectif`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are connecting to your database (for example, using mysqli):

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","dbname");

$check = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM objectif");

if ($check->num_rows == 0 || $check->fetch_field() == 0){
   echo "table is empty";
}else{
    echo "table is not empty";
}
```

Currently, your code isn't actually connecting to the database or querying the table - you are essentially just checking if the variable $query is empty (which it never will be, as it contains a string!

Running a query to fetch the number of records and checking that as per the code above is one way to do this.

Comment: good code sample, but try to provide more detail, so the OP can learn

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db");

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 1"))
{

    if ($obj = $result->fetch_object())
    {

        echo "NOT EMPTY";

    }
    else
    {

        echo "empty";

    }


    $result->close();

}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: good code sample, but try to provide more detail, so the OP can learn

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code :

```
$test_empty="SELECT * FROM objectif";
$query = mysql_query($test_empty);
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
     echo "It is Empty";
}
```

Comment: good code sample, but try to provide more detail, so the OP can learn

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions, as these have been deprecated. Please use mysqli or PDO instead.